# Child Coroutine Couldn't Be Cancelled

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to cancel child coroutine of a job but it won't be cancelled at all.

```
val job = launch(CoroutineName("X")) {
    println("I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    try {
        launch(coroutineContext) {
            println("I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            repeat(1000) {
                print(".")
                delay(1)
            }
        }
        delay(2000)
    } catch (ex: CancellationException) {
        println()
        println("outer exception")
    }
}

delay(100)
job.cancelChildren()
println()
println("Is outer cancelled ${job.isCancelled}")
```

Instead I've received this output:

```
I'm working in thread main @X#2
I'm working in thread main @X#3
.............................................................................
Is outer cancelled false
```

Comment: [`cancelChildren`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/cancel-children.html) does not alter the state of parent coroutine (`job`), if you assign variable to inner `launch` you will see that it is indeed canceled.

Comment: I thought it supposed to throw a CancellationException inside the parent coroutine.

Comment: If I will use coroutineScope{ ... } instead of launch { ... } then I can see the exception being thrown.

Comment: `launch` doesn't return a result so your catch block will never trigger due to it. It can only catch if `delay(2000)` throws when outer coroutine itself is canceled. In contrast `coroutineScope` does return a value so in case of cancellation that result is exception which is thrown.

Comment: I found out that only those with `suspend` in function declaration can be cancelled.
And `launch` is not one of them.

Comment: The outer coroutine is non-cancellable because you catch the `CancellationException`. When you request cancellation, it will go to the catch block and then complete normally. `job.isCancelled()` will return `false`.

Comment: @Pawel Even though `launch` won't throw the `CancellationException`, the parent coroutine would be cancelled asynchronously due to the failure of any child coroutine. Explicitly cancelling a coroutine does not constitute a failure, though, and that won't cancel the parent.